# What´s measure of the $\angle MNQ$ in the figure below?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference:
Calculate the measure of the $\angle MNQ$

If: H ➔ Orthocenter

M ➔ Midpoint of AB

N ➔ Midpoint of BC

Q ➔ Midpoint of AH

[image]

Follow the drawing with the relationships I found

[image]

Aqua Solution Image:

[image]

Comment: Again, can't you write all the supstances you have in the problem?

Comment: @Aqua   ..I didn't understand...could explain better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:  Points $M,N,K,Q$ are concyclic. Why?

> Nine point circle

So, we have: $$\angle MNQ = \angle MKQ = \angle MAK = 90^{\circ}- \angle B= 10^{\circ}$$

Comment: How $\small \angle MAK=\angle MKQ$?

Comment: Triangle $MAK$ is isosceles @ACB

Comment: Thank you very much for hep..Big idea the nine pont circle. It would be good to demonstrate $\triangle MAK$  is isosceles.

Comment: $triangle ABK~M =$  circumcenter $\therefore AM = MK$

Comment: Yes,@petaarantes